# Yii2 Cannot insert attribute(FK) with id(PK)

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i have id there is PK(Auto Inc) from models/order relation with FK id_order from models/preorder,  In my CRUD action for example actionCreate, i can't insert attibutes preorder to table because id(PK) from order always null. how do i fix this ?.

here's my controller

```
$cartPositions = Yii::$app->cart->getPositions();

  if (!$cartPositions or $cartPositions === null) {
      return $this->redirect(['index']);
  }

  $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
      'allModels' => $cartPositions,
  ]);

    $model = new Order();
    $model_po = new Preorder();
    $postData = Yii::$app->request->post();

        if ($model->load($postData) && $model_po->load($postData)) {
        //model->save(false);
        $model->status = 5;
        $model_po->id_order = $model->id;
        $model->total_cost = Yii::$app->cart->getCost();
        $model->date = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        $model->data = Yii::$app->cart->getSerialized();
        $model_po->name = $model->name;
        $model_po->phone = $model->phone;
        $model_po->remarks = $model->message;
        $model_po->created_at = $model->date;
        //$model_po->save();
        if (Model::validateMultiple([$model, $model_po]) && $model->save(false) && $model_po->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank You');
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose('order/html', [
                'model' => $model,
                //'model_po' => $model_po,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ])
                //->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['email']['from'])
                // ->setTo(Yii::$app->params['email']['to'])
                // ->setSubject('The site posted a new order')
                // ->send();

                ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['email']['from'])
                ->setTo(Yii::$app->params['email']['to'])
                ->setSubject('The site posted a new Preorder')
                ->send();

            Yii::$app->cart->removeAll();
            return $this->render('orderSuccess', [
                'model' => $model,
                //'model_po' => $model_po,
            ]);
        }
    } else
    {return $this->render('create_po', [
      'model' => $model,
      'model_po' => $model_po,
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);}
  }
```

models/order

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['status', 'total_cost', 'date', 'data', 'name', 'phone'], 'required'],
        [['code_order'], 'autonumber', 'format'=>'orderNum', 'digit'=>4],
        [['status', 'total_cost'], 'integer'],
        [['date'], 'safe'],
        [['data', 'message'], 'string'],
        [['name', 'email', 'phone'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}
```

model/preorders

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_order', 'address'], 'required'],
        [['id_order'], 'integer'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        [['address', 'remarks'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
        [['id_order'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Order::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_order' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

error info :

> Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_order' cannot be null
>   The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `preorder` (`address`, `id_order`, `name`, `phone`, `remarks`, `created_at`) VALUES ('', NULL, 'Name', '121324325', '', '2016-07-23 17:01')

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1048
    [2] => Column 'id_order' cannot be null

i was try getPrimaryKey() and last insert id() not work and i was try to remove $modelpo->id_order = $model->id the result is two tables filled but id_order is 0

Answer (score 1):

$model->id is null until successful $model->save() so you should not assign its value to $model_po->id_order before that.

This is a good place for [transaction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-transaction.html) so you can validate data first, then make sure Order is saved and then save Preorder with proper id_order.

Take a look at [link()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#saving-relations) method as well.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use afterSave()? it will definetely solve your problem

Comment: Thank You. i use transaction now.